# Solving $x^2 \equiv 12 \pmod{13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Solve $x^2 \equiv 12 \pmod{13}$.

I was instructed on defining $12$ using primitive roots and then Lagrange's theorem.

It seems that ord$_{13}(12) = 2$, but this isn't a primitive root since $\phi(13) = 12$ and ord$_{13}(12) \ne \phi(13)$. Any hints to proceed would be appreciated. I feel like I missing something here...

Comment: We have $x^2=0$ in $\Bbb Z/12$, so of course $x=0$ is a solution and also $6\cdot 6=36=0$ etc.

Comment: Did you mean $\mod 13$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I did! Thanks.

Comment: Now we have $x^2=-1$ in the finite field $\Bbb F_{13}$, which can only have at most two solutions, because we have a field! Actually, we have solved this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929253/number-of-soulutions-for-bar-xm-bar-a-in-mathbbz-p?noredirect=1&lq=1). Just take $p=13$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2$ is a primitive root mod $13$, so $2^{12}\equiv1$, $2^6\equiv-1$,

and the solutions to $x^{12}\equiv12\equiv-1$ are $2^3\equiv8$ and $2^9\equiv5\equiv-8$.

(You can see that $8^2=64=65-1\equiv12\bmod13$, and $5^2=25=26-1\equiv12\bmod13$.)

These are the primitive fourth roots of unity mod $13$.

$4\times3\equiv4\times9\equiv0\bmod12$, and $2\times3\equiv2\times9\not\equiv0\bmod12$.